# How to add multiple packages with forked repositories?

Tags: composer-php

I want to add multiple packages that I have forked in composer.

I have used the way that is described in https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository but what is described there is for only one package and I want to do it for multiple packages. How should I declare it? I want to add extra repository links.

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/igorw/monolog"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-bugfix"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.

```
{
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/igorw/monolog" },
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/igorw/dialog" }
    ],
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-bugfix",
        "dialog/dialog": "dev-bugfix"
    },
}
```